# How to activate IIS on windows 7 ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, iis

The thing is that when I go to features and activate IIS, the loading bar appears,it goes all the way to ~ 90% then the computer freezes...

Any ideea why that's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Disable any security software you have running before install.

Comment: I'll try that, but it's pretty time consuming. I have to restart after each failed attempt...